# Is there a way to discover VMs using Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, infrastructure

Infrastructure team members are creating, deleting and modifying resources in GCP project using console. Security team wants to scan the infra and check weather proper security measures are taken care
I am tryng to create a terraform script which will:
1. Take project ID as input and list all instances of the given project.
2. Loop all the instances and check if the security controls are in place.
3. If any security control is missing, terraform script will be modifying the resource(VM).

I have to repeat the same steps for all resoources available in project like subnet, cloud storage buckets, firewalls etc.

As per my initial investigation to do such  task We will have to import the resources to terraform using "terraform import" command and after that will  have to think of loops.

Now it looks like using APIs of GCP is the best fit for this task, as it looks terraform is not the good choice for this kind of tasks and I am not sure weather it is achievable using teffarform.

Can somebody provide any directions here?

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use Terraform for this? If Terraform is being used for the initial creation of these resources and so is in state files elsewhere then importing them into another state file is going to cause you a lot of issues.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Technical Architect has decided to go with terraform. Terraform is not used to create these resources. I am beginner of terraform and dont know the capabilities of it. Looking for expert advise here.

Comment: It is doable but it's not what it's designed for and you're going to spend too much time trying to work around things. I'm not a GCP person but this kind of thing would normally be done in AWS with AWS Config among other things. Depending on what you want to do you might be better off with GCP's Security Command Center product.

Answer (score 1):

Curious if by "console" you mean the gcp console (aka by hand), because if you are not already using terraform to create the resources (and do not plan to in the future), then terraform is not the correct tool for what you're describing. I'd actually argue it is increasing the complexity.

Mostly because:

1. The import feature is not intended for this kind of use case and we still find regular issues with it. Maybe 1 time for a few resources, but not for entire environments and not without it becoming the future source of truth. Projects such as [terraforming](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/terraforming-gcp) do their best but still face wild west issues in complex environments. Not all resources even support importing
2. Terraform will not tell you anything about the VM's that you wouldn't know from the GCP cli already. If you need more information to make an assessment about the controls then you will need to use another tool or have some complicated provisioners. Provisioners at best would end up being a wrapper around other tooling you could probably use directly.

Honestly, I'm worried your team is trying to avoid the pain of converting older practices to IaC. It's uncomfortable and challenging, but yields better fruit in the long run then the path you're describing.

Digress, if you have infra created via terraform then I'd invest more time in some other practices that can accomplish the same results. Some other options are: 1) enforce best practices via parent modules that security has "blessed", 2) implement some CI on your terraform, 3) AWS has Config and Systems Manager, not sure if GCP has an equivalent but I would look around. Also it's worth evaluating using different technologies for different layers of abstraction. What checks your OS might be different from what checks your security groups and that's ok. Knowing is half the battle and might make for a more sane first version then automatic remediation.

With or without terraform, there is a an ecosystem of both products and opensource projects that can help with the compliance or control enforcement. Take a look at tools like [inspec](https://www.inspec.io/), [sentinel](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/introduction-sentinel-compliance-policy-as-code), or [salstack](https://www.saltstack.com/) for inspiration.